# SPFX Extension Issues in Edge

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have built an extension and deployed the extension in-app catalog but it showing an error message in the edge browser but completely fine in chrome.

Erro Loading debug manifests.....
[image]

Steps I followed:
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship

and deployed the solutions
Locally working fine but issues after deploye in edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a caching issue. Edge is still trying to load the extension from the local debugging host started when you run `gulp serve`.

Try accessing the SharePoint site using a private (incognito) browser session in Edge to confirm. If it loads correctly in that session, then try doing a full reload using CTRL-F5 in the regular (non-incognito) browser session. You can also trying clearing cookies and local storage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help